# How do I restore the display state in FreeCommander?

Tags: freecommander

How can the display state in FreeCommander for files/folders be restored to the initial state (as after installation)?

I have inadvertently changed the display state, see below, in [FreeCommander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCommander) and I can't figure out how to get back to the previous state. I don't want both the folder hierarchy and the one folder view in each panel. I only want the one folder view in each panel, corresponding to the scratched out parts not being there in this illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, on the right side, just above the white D drive icon, there are 2 blue buttons. The left one is the tree view icon - click it and it will turn off the area you don't want. You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

You will have to click in each of the file views to turn off both tree views.

Comment: Ah, yes. What a relief.